# Drupal 7 - add the same class to all <img> tags in the content area

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have an online Portfolio site that I transferred from a static HTML into Drupal 7 - trying to learn Drupal. I have 3 separate pages that have image galleries. I have a javascript (.js) file that adds reflections onto any image that carries a class="reflect". In HTML, this is easy to do, obviously, and it was working just fine in my static site. I would like to continue using it, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add the required class to my images.

Desired Result:

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="reflect" />
<img src="image2.jpg" class="reflect" />
<img src="image3.jpg" class="reflect" />
```

and so on...

**Addressing other found suggestions:**
All of my images currently do not carry a class at all.
I did find a couple of proposed work-around's but they didn't quite suit my needs as I need to add the same class to all of the  tags present, while ignoring any elsewhere, such as the header and footer. Plus, while I know a little PHP, I'm not great at it. Drupal is supposed to be completely dynamic so I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Are all your images instances of the same field?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're asking, I don't think so. I believe I've created different ones for each gallery. But I may be thinking of something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement [theme_image](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7)() to do that, in your `template.php` file just type the following:

```
function [YOUR_THEME]_image($variables)
{
    $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
    $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);

    $attributes['class'][] = 'reflect'; // add the class name here

    foreach (array('width', 'height', 'alt', 'title') as $key) {

        if (isset($variables[$key])) {
            $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
        }
    }

    return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
}
```

Kindly note that this class will be added to all the images across the site.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Well, this does do the trick and does add the desired class to all of my images. So I thank you for that. As I feared though, it carries over into undesired areas, such as other pages of the site which contain images but aren't part of my galleries - my blog for example. Is there any way of telling it to ignore specific nodes or pages or regions or something? Or perhaps to focus this in so it only works within the 3 image galleries?

Comment: So I'm guessing that's a no?

Comment: Are the images delivered to the page via a `view` or a `node page`?!

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're being fed in through a view - a gallery module that uses Views to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your images in a div and assign a class through it to all images something like this:

```
<div class="imgDiv">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="image3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

And define your class:

```
.imgDiv img {
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not at all what I need. This isn't a CSS issue, this is an HTML issue (possibly a PHP issue depending on how you look at it). Frankly, it seems as if you didn't even read the whole question because I thought I made it pretty clear. What I need is all of my images to have a class="reflect". If my images don't look like I displayed above, then it's not right and won't work. The .js I'm using won't do it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can wrapper div with id and add css for img tag in css file. You can also use jquery.